# How to read multiple files with specific character or number using a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a directory with a bunch of .tif files like: tnt_xxx_2015.tif, tnt_xxx_2016.tif, tnt_xxx_2017.tif......tnt_xxx_2100.tif. 'tnt' is one of the variable names, and for each year "xxx" represents multiple strings. The years are from 2015 to 2100.So I want to find all files that the variable name and year are the same values.I tried to find all files with the variable 'tnt' in same year first:

```
for (i in 2015:2100)
{
   myfiles = Sys.glob("*i.tif")
}
```

But it doesn't work. It won't accept wildcards; it needs an exact match on the file name. `Sys.glob("2015.tif")` runs successfully.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```r
for(I in 2015:2100){
  myfiles <- list.files(pattern=paste0(i, ".tif$"))
}
```

This replicates your code above, but will overwrite `myfiles` each time through the loop.  If you want to just grab all the files in one vector, you could do the following:

```r
myfiles <- NULL
for(I in 2015:2100){
  myfiles <- c(myfiles, list.files(pattern=paste0(i, ".tif$")))
}
```

Comment: It works! 
Like I mentioned before, there are several variable names such as:  `varname=c(“ta”,”tnt”,”tntrl”,”ts”,”tsl”)` The strings between the variable name and the year are of different lengths. So what if I want to add variable name in the loop as well? like this: `myfiles <- list.files(pattern=paste0(varname,"*",i, ".tif$"))`